# Create PDF from html in react-js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

**I need to create a PDF from HTML inside a react-js app**.

Many packages I have found prompt a download button in the browser ( like [jsPDF](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf) ), but I actually need the PDF as a binary string. I need this string to be send to a private API that stores this PDF ( binary string ) in S3 as a PDF file. This private API call already exists, and I can not change anything from this code.

I am struggeling to understand why this is so hard. How would you go about converting HTML to PDF binary string? Thanks for any suggestions, packages, ... It can be javscript, if I can implement it inside my reactJS app.

Bonus points if the solution can accept HTML tags, since the input is done inside an WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 0):

This server side solution works with any HTML framework.
https://github.com/PDFTron/web-to-pdf

This is from the company I work for, but is AGPL-3.0 so you should be able to use no problem.