# Html To Pdf with bootstrap

Tags: html, pdf, pdf-generation, jspdf, html-to-pdf

I am making a payment gateway for a client using authorize.net which I have succesfully managed to do so. Now the client wants to have a receipt for the user to download on the success page. I have all the necessary data in php variables stored for printing. But the invoice that my client wants has a specific design , there are a lot of alignments, lines. I have tried jspdf. but doesnt go with the styling of my html. and I dont know how to align things in it myself. Can anyone give me a go-ahead what should I do to print pdf anyway I like.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are still looking for a solution, or someone else comes across this question, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61484708/3761687

While that question was about React, the solution works with any framework.